# How to connect to existing mongodb database

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb server on my system. For testing purpose i created different database using different port. E.g.

- dbname1 - SomepathIndrive -- Port
- dbname2 - SomepathIndrive -- Port
- dbname3 - SomepathIndrive -- Port

Now how do connect/start dbname2 or dbname 3 ?

When I use mongo command , it connects to default port and default database

Comment: `mongo dbname1` etc etc. There is a manual. And even command line help. Honestly it's not really clear if you are talking about database namespaces or something completely different.

Comment: i created database with port 60000 which I was using in my application

Comment: you created database on different port? with which command can you add it please

Answer (score 1):

As you said

```
mongo
```

command will connect to the server on the default port, if you want to connect to the server on different port use

```
mongo --port portnumber
```

When you are connected to mongo shell, command

```
show dbs
```

will result in list of all available databasses and to start using one of these use command

```
use databasename
```

Here's the link to the mongodb documentation about mongo Shell:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/